# why $ \sin \theta = \frac{7}{8} \cos \theta$?

Tags: trigonometry

I have an example:

$$ \tan \theta = \frac{\sin \theta}{\cos \theta} = \frac{7}{8} $$

and then this equation is true? why there is cos multiplied?:

$$ \sin \theta = \frac{7}{8} \cos \theta$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $\dfrac{\sin \theta}{\cos \theta} = \dfrac{7}{8}$

Multiply both side by $\cos \theta$

You get $\dfrac{\sin \theta}{\cos \theta} \times\cos \theta = \dfrac{7}{8} \cos \theta$

So you get $\sin \theta = \dfrac78 \cos \theta$

Answer (score 1):

Your initial equation is $$\frac ab = \frac 78.$$ If you multiply this equation by $b$, you get

$$\frac ab \cdot b = \frac 78\cdot b\\
\frac{a\cdot b}{b} = \frac78\cdot b\\
a =\frac78\cdot b$$

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can interpret the situation like this, if you are not familiar with the mechanism of equation.

If $$\frac{\sin \theta}{\cos \theta} = \frac{7}{8}$$

We can say $\sin \theta=7\cdot(something), \cos \theta=8\cdot(something)$,

so $\sin \theta=\frac18{\cos\theta\cdot7=\frac78\cos\theta}$.